# Convenient workflow when changing a custom library

Tags: git

I have a custom ImageManipulation library that is based on a particular external library. (This is on master branch.) Right now, I want to test how another library would work, so I would do:

```
git checkout -b experiment_new_library
```

If then, I decide this works fine, and I merge it into master, what would be the good approach in order to be able to have ‘saved’ somehow that old master branch with the old Image library? How should you save that state in case you want to rollback to it?

Answer (score 0):

You can always go back to older commits, it’s the purpose of VCS. If you want to name or “mark” the particular commit (state), so you can easily find it later, use git [tag](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics-Tagging).

However, if you want to maintain your code for more then one version of the external library (maybe backport security fixes etc.), then it’ll be better to use separate branch for each version of the external library.

Answer (score 0):

To save your master branch at its current position for easy future `checkout`, simply run

```
git branch master_backup master
```

where you can replace master_backup as any branch name you like, as long as it does not yet exist.
If you wish to store it on `origin` (or any other remote server), you can quite easily achieve that:

```
git push origin master:master_backup
```

This will create a new branch in the remote `origin` with the name `master_backup`, with the current content of your local `master`. Feel free to change the names as needed.

Having said that, you don't really need a backup branch, since git stores the history. All you need to do is find the merge commit id (which it's comment will default to `Merge branch 'experiment_new_library'`), then simply run either of the following (replace `<commit_id>` with the commit id of the merge):

```
git checkout <commit_id>^                   # This will leave you in a detached HEAD
git checkout -b before_merge <commit_id>^   # This will create a branch called before_merge and switch to it.
git branch before_merge <commit_id>^        # Same as above, but don't switch to the created branch
```

The above methods will always work, regardless of if you "backed-up" the branch or not.
Notice the importance of adding the caret (`^`) sign adjacent to the commit id (no spaces). This tells git to check out one-commit-before the given commit id.

If, in the future, for any reason, you decide to switch back to the old library, but already accumulated some changes in `master` which you do not want to lose, you can either `rebase --onto` (although a rebase in this situation is less advised) or `revert` the merge itself:

```
git rebase --onto <commit_id>^ <commit_id> master  # Again, less advised. Better use the next line:
git revert -m1 <commit_id>
```

For all of this to be true, you must perform an actual merge. By default, `git merge` will attempt to apply the changes in a fast-forward manner (unless you have changes in `master` which are not contained in `experiment_new_library`), which is not what you want. Make sure that you merge to master using the following parameter:

```
git checkout master
git merge --no-ff experiment_new_library
```